# Sort values in child views of custom listview android

Tags: android, android-listview

I designing a custom `ListView` ,which has more child view

I have ideas about sorting the `ListView`data in "Asc" or "Desc" order ,that retrieves data directly from database , but in my case I used CustomSimpleCursorAdapter , I requires to sort data in `TextView` depending upon the values that is:

1. today
2. tomorrow
3. more than 2 days i.e; 354

### CustomSimpleCursorAdapter .java

```
//Days remaining for BirthDay  

        String year=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_YEAR));
        String month=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_MONTH));  
        String date=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.EVENT_DATE));
        String remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);

         Calendar today=Calendar.getInstance();
         int CMonth=(today.get(Calendar.MONDAY)+1);
         int CDate=(today.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));


         //checking whether the BD is on TODAY

         if (remainingDays.equals("1") && (CDate==Integer.parseInt(date) && (CMonth)==Integer.parseInt(month))) {                        
             viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 20);
             viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTypeface(fontRoboto_Regular);
             viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#00CC33"));
             remainingDays="today";              
        }

         //checking whether the BD is on TOMORROW
         else if (remainingDays.equals("1")) {           
             viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 17);
             viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0099"));
             remainingDays="tomorrow";
             viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTypeface(fontRoboto_Regular);
        }


       //checking how many days remaining BD
         else{
          remainingDays=BirthdayCalculation.getDaysRemainingForNextBirthDay(year, month, date);
          viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 27);
          viewHolder.txtDaysRemainigValue.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#990000"));

         }
```

Here's [Screen Shot link](https://www.flickr.com/photos/109729836@N08/13077544373/)

Answer (score 0):

If you get the data in database, you can use ASC or DESC and put ArrayList.
another way is you can use Collections.sort(). but you must data class implements comparable and overriding compare method.

Comment: What your data? it's saved in database? or input data in your code?

Comment: Please see mu comment to@Karakuri

Comment: @karthik This link help comare class type. [link]http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-object-sorting-example-comparable-and-comparator/

Answer (score 0):

When you query your database, you should use an "order by" clause. For example, [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) takes the order by clause as the last argument. I don't know how you store your dates and times in your database, but if it's something SQLite can recognize and provide sorting on, then it should work. The following will query for all columns on a table named "table" with no where clause, no "group by" clause, no "having" clause, and order by the time column descending (use ASC for ascending if you want that instead):

`database.query("table", null, null, null, null, null, "time DESC");`

**EDIT**

If you can't store the exact data you want (in this case days remaining until an event), I can only see two options:

**1).** After getting the cursor, you iterate over the results and compose a new sorted list. You could make some kind of model object in java, read the values into it from the cursor, and sort them with a comparator function. At that point you probably would not use a `CursorAdapter` any more. It's quite easy to build your own `ListAdapter` - I recommend you watch [The World of Listview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70)

**2).** Since the query methods take strings, you can actually compose more complicated queries so that SQLite provides you the data you DO want (and still sort it for you as well). If your times are stored as longs, you could do something like this:

```
long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
String timeAsString = Long.toString(currentTime);
String remainingTimeColumn = "(time_column - " + timeAsString + ") AS remaining_time";

// compose query
String table = "table";
String[] columns = new String[] {"column1", "column2", ..., "columnN", remainingTimeColumn};
String order = "remaining_time ASC";

// query
Cursor cursor = database.query(table, columns, null, null, null, null, order);

// later, get remaining time from cursor row
long remainingTime = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("remaining_time"));
```

In this case `"time_column"` is the name of the column that stores the event time. What this is doing is creating an additional column with the name `"remaining_time"`, which is calculated from one of the actual column values. The results are then sorted by that synthesized column. The cursor you get back will contain this column and these values, you just need to have the proper column name to access them.

Since I don't know the details of your data format, I can't say this is exactly how your query should look, but the idea should be clear. You can work out the finer details from here...

Comment: I want to sort textview values which shows "Remainig days"..Remaining days is not stored in data base . I am accessing the method dyanamically in CustomSimpleCursorAdapter.java

Comment: Depending on how big the data set is, might there be an issue with dumping it all into a list?  Or is that only if your list has thousands of elements?